# Magento 1.8.1 - Customer grid date display bug

Tags: customer, ce-1.8.1.0, backend

I'm having a problem with the signup date display in customer grid: when a customer signs up the date is wrongly entered in the database, our date format is yyyy-mm-dd, but when the day is before the 12th of the month, it switches to yyyy-dd-mm, resulting in a wrong display in customer grid.
For example, if a customer signs up on 2014-08-11, it'll be displayed as 2014-11-08, but if it's 2014-08-13 it's fine.
Seems like it's a native bug since we didn't touch the customer model, did anyone encountered that issue?
Thanks

Comment: better to use drop downs for date,month and year at frontend, for year you can even keep the text field.